# Vaadin combobox.select() does not work no matter what I do

Tags: mysql, hibernate, combobox, vaadin

I am writing a basic CRUD app using Hibernate MySQL. 
Adding new records is fine but I'm having some trouble getting an existing record's value to appear as the selected item by default when editing an existing record. 
Here is the relevant code:

```
Criteria criteriaz = session.createCriteria(Organisation.class);
final List<Organisation> orgList = criteriaz.list();
BeanItemContainer<Organisation> srcOrgs = new BeanItemContainer<Organisation>(Organisation.class);
srcOrgs.addAll(orgList);

organisationId.setInvalidAllowed(false);
organisationId.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
organisationId.setContainerDataSource(srcOrgs);
organisationId.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
organisationId.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");

for (Organisation mOrg : orgList) {
                    if (mOrg.getRowid().equals(activity.getOrganisationId())) 
                        mOrgID = mOrg.getName();  
                }

organisationId.select(mOrgID);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: With minor changes, both the answers are (almost) correct. The main idea if you look at the [bean item contaier](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html#datamodel.container.beanitemcontainer), is that it uses the beans themselves as ids for the items. Thus, after identifying the organization (by its id, name, etc) which should be selected, you can use the particular instance to select the appropriate item from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just:

```
for (Organisation mOrg : orgList) {
    if (mOrg.getRowid().equals(activity.getOrganisationId())) 
        organisationId.select(mOrg);
        break;
    }
```

BeanItemContainer contains beans as IDs, so you always work with beans only.

Comment: Close but actually you need to select by `mOrg` as `activity.getOrganisationId()` looks like will return the id of an `Organisation` object.

Comment: This is almost identical to an answer I received over at the Vaadin Forum so I am marking it as correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although you set the caption property id to name it does not change the identifier ID for the items. So you can use the following on conjunction with BeanItemContainer:

```
organisationId.select(orgList.get(mOrgID));
```

and change this

```
mOrgID = mOrg.getName(); 
to
mOrgID = mOrg;
```

---

To make @Morfic happy:

```
organisationId.select(orgList.get(orgList.indexOf(mOrgID)));
```

Comment: Why the `orgList.get(mOrgID)`? You already have `mOrg`, so simply call `organisationId.select(mOrg)` and exit the loop.

Comment: No offence, but I find it confusing... `orgList.get(mOrgID)` would not even compile because the `List.get(int index)` expects an `int` argument and you're supplying an instance of `Organisation`.

Comment: @Morfic Yup, use indexOf.